# Authenticate user to Salesforce based on pre Desktop authentication

Tags: authentication, open-id-connect, jwt

I am using OpenID connect flow to authenticate to Salesforce community using a third party Identity provider service. I have configured all settings in Salesforce and it is working fine when initiated:

1. Directly from the browser using the AUTH Provider URL (    - https://test.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/{{orgID}}/{{auth_provider_name}}?community={{community URL}}
2. By entering the community URL and user will be automatically redirected to Identity provider authentication page (I have disabled the default Salesforce login option and Only Auth provider is available)

It takes the user to Identity Provider authorisation page and if authorised, user will be logged in.

In addition to that, my client has a desktop application which will also redirect users to community URL in a browser. Once redirected the user shouldn't need to authorise (using the Identity provider screen), as he is pre authorised in the desktop application using the same third party Identity Provider service.

I came across JWT flow to support such scenario. Does anybody has any insights on this matter?

More details on JWT flow : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=0

Thanks.

Comment: So, basically, you want to use JWT for SSO using the desktop application?

Comment: Yes, I’d like the user to be able to click a link in the desktop app that points to a page in a community, and have that open up the user’s preferred web browser and take them to the community page without them having to re-authenticate in the browser. This doesn’t necessarily need to be with JWT, but I’m wondering what the options are. Thanks!